# Trouble with HP printer

Tags: printer

I have a HP Photosmart C3180 (it's a printer/scanner). For some reason, it recently stopped working. The power light is blinking (I think all the other lights are one, but don't remember, I'm not there right now), and the only way to turn it off is to unplug it. It won't print anything, and when you put a page in the tray it sucks it in without printing anything on it and stops when the paper is on its way out (Again, I don't remember how we managed to get it out, sorry).

This printer is hooked up to a computer running XP, but it doesn't work either when printing from the network. Weirdly, the scanner works fine.

Do you have any ideas on what could be the problem? Could it be a driver problem?

By the way, sorry if the question lacks a bit of detail. I don't know much about printers, and I don't have it here so I can't remember exactly all the details. If needed I can update the question tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Please update your question whenyou are at the printer.  The light combination is often an error code that will help.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that. I just thought that maybe meanwhile someone could have some general advice.

Comment: If you haven't already, try unplugging the power and then plugging it back it. I've had an HP printer lock up and it needed a power cycle to restore it to working order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firmware is bad. You'll have to send it in to HP for repairs unless you can find a local shop that can unbrick it.

The Scanner portion is functionally seperate from the Printer part, they just have a shared USB connection.

Comment: That seemed to be the case. We took it for repairs, though I don't have it back yet.